# Play store libpng secuirty issue Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, libpng

I am trying to deploy my Flutter app to the play store but it got rejected and they asked me to upgrade libpng version due to some vulnerabilities (The vulnerabilities were fixed in libpng v1.0.66, v.1.2.56, v.1.4.19, v1.5.26 or higher.) but I am not sure what should I upgrade because I didn't add the library manually and I am not using OpenCV.
Any ideas are appreciated.